# How do I handle different versions of a class that I'm extending in PHP?

Tags: php, versioning

*Restraint 1: I can't control what class `A` is, nor the version of the bigger software it comes from. I have to submit its rules. It doesn't have versioning, nothing, it's just a class I need. We're talking about WordPress, so, it's not like these things will be added :)*

*Restraint 2: I must ship my product as-is. I am not going to be able to redirect customers to `V5.1` of my plugin.*

There's a class `A` that I'm extending inside `B`, we are now on `version 5.0`:

```
class B extends A
{
    public function feedback( $string )
}
```

Now, as you can see, `A` has this function `feedback` which only takes one parameter. All's good, it should work. But what happens if `A` changes it? Well, when upgrading to `version 5.1`, our `feedback` function looks like this:

`public function feedback( $string, ...$args )`

And once we re-run our code we are given the `Declaration of B::feedback( $string ) must be compatible with A::feedback( $string, ...$args )` error.

I want my customers to be able to use the product on a few versions of their software. As my product is a plug-in, I have to respect and try to make it work for all these versions.

How do I handle this?

Comment: use semver versioning, and let the consumer worry about it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't have that choice. The `A` class is not mine to control, nor is the version of the overall software. I have to submit to their rules.

Comment: if library you depend on does not support backward compatibility - then you have to maintain multiple version of your software

Comment: @IłyaBursov Damn. Can you link me some good articles on how can I ensure that this doesn't happen to developers that'd want to use my code? Specifically for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing software that has a dependency and you want to support multiple, incompatible versions, then generally that means you also need to make an equal number of versions of your own software.

This does not have to be as hard to maintain as you think. It's not that difficult to have multiple active git branches, and any changes that applies to each 'target' can be merged across or cherry-picked.

Comment: You might be able to hack your way around this, but I feel this is a valid solution for this problem and I would argue a very common way developers deal with supporting multiple versions. Composer will actually be smart enough to pick the right version of *your* package depending on what version the user has installed.

Comment: I agree. If nothing else, I will go this route, otherwise my product can't work, so, of course I must, but just asking if there's no better solution. I want to do things the right way.

Comment: I've maintained several PHP packages, each targetting a maximum PHP version (5.2, 5.4 and 7 I believe). It was not difficult to to this and it's kind of a similar problem. It's nice also nice if your main branch is both the state of the art of your package, and the state of the art of the dependency. I would focus on the perceived friction with maintaining multiple versions and see if you can remove that friction.

Comment: Can you link some code to that or edit your answer? Just trying to see if there's some nice way to do it. I'm beyond happy with the quality of my software. A hack here and there to get the work done won't kill anyone, if there's no other option.

Comment: Here's an example of a package of mine that has a version for PHP 5 and one for PHP 7:

https://packagist.org/packages/sabre/uri

Comment: When I need to fix a bug that applies to both, I tend to make a pull request for the `1.x` branch, and after that's merged I will *also* merge to `master`, resolve all conflicts and make sure that all tests work.

Comment: There would have been no other way in this case because I wanted people on the PHP 7 version to be able to take advantage of strict typing.

Comment: It's way cleaner to manage changes in github branches and via merging vs. doing it *inside* the code with all kinds of conditionals.

Comment: P.S. I just noticed this is about wordpress, and I don't know if managing multiple versions and dependencies works nearly as well as plain composer packages would, so ymmv. I would hate to rely on users to *manually* manage versions so that might change things.